# How to create Sencha Touch/Ext style docs

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

We are building inhouse Sencha Touch and Ext JS components. Is there any tool using which we can create docs like those available on Official Sencha Docs.

Comment: The tool used is call JSDuck. It's open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs can be generated by tool JSDuck. Its available here. https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck

Thnx @evan trimboli